# need to add active class only for first element in jquery.each

Tags: jquery, class, append

I have used the following code to append a `div` to another `div`.The appended `div` has a series of dynamic images.I need to add a class called `active` only to the first `img` in the loop.

```
var items = [];
jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
  jQuery('#imagenn').append('<div class="item"> <div  class="col-xs-2"> <img src="' + val+ '" />    </div></div>'); 
});
```

I need to update only first iteration as `<div class="item active"`.

ie expected output

```
<div class="item active"> <div class="col-xs-2"> <img src="test.png" /></div></div>
<div class="item"> <div class="col-xs-2"> <img src="test.png" /></div></div>
<div class="item"> <div class="col-xs-2"> <img src="test.png" /></div></div>
```

and so on.
Please help me to do this.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add a little more detail and code. Currently, it's not clear from where `data`, `key`, and `imagenn` are coming.

Comment: i will get image path as value inside .each function. need to add class active in the first append.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:first` filter after loop

```js
var data = ['test', 'test', 'test'];

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  $('#imagenn').append('<div class="item"> <div  class="col-xs-2"> <img src="' + val + '" />    </div></div>');
});

$('#imagenn .item:first').addClass('active')
```

```css
.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="imagenn"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `active` class to the `img` if the `key` value is `0`.

Here's the code.

```
var items = [];
jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
  let imageClass = key === 0 ? val : val += ' active';
  jQuery('#imagenn').append('<div class="item"> <div  class="col-xs-2"> <img src="' + val+ '" />    </div></div>'); 
});
```